# Why doesn't the SELECT query select what it should select?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have never experienced this before **so I wonder what to look after in the code to solve it**.

This is the code - which should work?

```
    $time = strtotime("-$a2 year", time());
$date = date("Y", $time);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE country='$country' AND state='$state'";

if(!empty($a2) && empty($a1)){
  $query .= " AND year<=";
  $query .= " '$date'";
  $query .= " AND day<=";
  $query .= " '$todayd'";
  $query .= " AND month<=";
  $query .= " '$todaym'";
 }
if(..){}
if(..){}
     $result = $query;

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"$result");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
    .......
```

If I echo the string $query it shows:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE country='Spain' AND state='Madrid'
```

But the selected/shown users have all different kinds of countires and states

Comment: Why are you overwriting the variable? It is not something that will solve your issue (there is not enough to go on here), but it does seem strange.

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't make sense.  Need more code.

Comment: What happens when you run that same query in the database?

Comment: Without seeing some example data it would be difficult to identify the problem. The query itself looks ok. Btw: You get the result from `mysqli_query()` and give "the Query" to it and `mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches a row from the result. For better understanding rename the variables.

Comment: Let me guess you have also `OR condition` maybe even like `OR 1=1` :)

Comment: Yes i have 1 or 2 OR conditions. Why?

Comment: So, this is _not_ your _actual_ code?

Comment: Why?? Because no one can help you if you post part of your code...

Comment: I guess the other, not shown `OR clauses` are introduced within the `if(..){}` placeholders that you DID show?

Answer (score -1):

From author comment:

> Yes i have 1 or 2 OR conditions. Why?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE country='$country' AND state='$state' OR ...
```

Boolean logic says:

```
(p1 AND p2) OR p3
```

If p3 is true entire condition is true. The case is you get rows for (p1 AND p2) + records that are satisfied by p3.

**[`Disjunction`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction)**

> "A or B" is true if A is true, or if B is true, or if both A and B are
>   true.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(country VARCHAR(100), state VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab
VALUES ('Spain', 'Madrid'), ('Russia','Moscow');

SELECT *
FROM #tab
WHERE country='Spain' AND state='Madrid' OR 4 > 2
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384658)**</kbd>

Comment: **For funny downvoter leave comment so I can reply/improve my answer**